# Sum of the reciprocals of the primes squared

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does anyone know of any information/work on this sum?   I found absolutely nothing on the web about it.

Comment: Naive question: why does one expect the value of this sum to have interesting properties?

Comment: Ah, I see that someone more learned than me has provided links below, which presumably answer my question

Comment: Kudos for not deleting "why does one expect the value of this sum to have interesting properties?" In retrospect, it was extremely degrading to Ethan Brush, wasn't it? - Well, he never came back to this site.

Comment: @niloderoock Your definition of "extremely degrading" doesn't agree with mine.

Comment: Something must have been deleted because I don't understand my own reaction from what I can see here.

Answer (score 40):

This would be $P(2)$, where $P$ is the "prime zeta function," q.v.

A couple of very old references are C. W. Merrifield, The Sums of the Series of Reciprocals of the Prime Numbers and of Their Powers, Proc. Roy. Soc. London 33 (1881) 4–10. doi:10.1098/rspl.1881.0063. JSTOR 113877

J. W. L. Glaisher, On the Sums of Inverse Powers of the Prime Numbers, Quart. J. Math. 25 (1891) 347–362.

EDIT: A more recent source is Steven R Finch, Mathematical Constants, page 95: The sum of the squared reciprocals of primes is $$N=\sum_p{1\over p^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\mu(k)\over k}\log(\zeta(2k))=0.4522474200\dots$$

Comment: suspiciously close to the lb/kg ratio....

Comment: An older source is in Euler's Introductio in analysin infinitorum, volume 1 chapter 15  (1748) http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E101.html  . An English translation is available here http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/introductiontoanalysisvol1.htm

Comment: In particular, on page 480 of http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/euler/introductiontoanalysisvolone/ch15vol1.pdf

Comment: hahaha, @YaakovBaruch nice; $4/(\pi^2 -1)$ is close too hahaha