# sum of reciprocals of pairs of primes and floor functions

Tags: nt.number-theory

It was [not hard to google](http://math.stanford.edu/~dlitt/exposnotes/primes1mod4.pdf) that the simpler sum $\displaystyle \sum_{p < N} \frac{1}{p} = c + \log \log N $ so it is divergent.

The [sum of reciprocals of primes squared](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared)  also converges $\displaystyle \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} = 0.4522\dots$

---

Does 
$\displaystyle \sum_{p} \frac{1}{p} \left\{ \frac{N}{p} \right\}  $ stay bounded as $N$ gets large?
What about $\displaystyle \sum_{p,q } \frac{1}{pq} \left\{ \frac{N}{pq} \right\}  $ for large $N$?

Maybe it's necessary to say $p,q < N$.  This is related to my [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95836/error-to-sum-of-euler-phi-functions) on the Euler $\phi$-function

Comment: The first sum is asymptotic to $(1-\gamma)\log \log N$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant, and the second sum is asymptotic to $c_2(\log \log N)^2$ for some constant $c_2$.  I am very curious though, how does this relate to your earlier question?